# file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in line C: xampp

Tags: php, file-handling

I would like to point out before I get into this that I am a PHP newb, and I have been struggling for a while with this before finally deciding that I don't know what I'm doing with

```
function extract_bin($Filename, $output){
    global $template;
    global $BinColumnDelimiter;
    global $BinLineEnd;

    $decodedfile = fopen($output,'w+');
    $decodedfilecontents  = "";

    $handle = fopen($Filename, "r");

    if ($handle) {

        foreach ( $template as $ColName=>$Endians) 
            $decodedfilecontents .= $ColName.$BinColumnDelimiter;

        $decodedfilecontents .= $BinLineEnd;

        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $lastLine = '';

            foreach ($template as $ColName => $Endians){
                $hex  = bin2hex(fread($handle,$Endians));

                if ( $Endians <= 4) {
                    $val = hexdec(decodehex($hex));
                    if ( $val == 4294967295  ) $val = -1;
                    $lastLine .= $val.$BinColumnDelimiter;
                } else {
                    $lastLine .= str_replace("\t"," ",hex2str($hex)).$BinColumnDelimiter;
                }
            }

            if ( ! feof($handle))
                $decodedfilecontents .= $lastLine.$BinLineEnd;
        }

        fclose($handle);

        fwrite($decodedfile,$decodedfilecontents);
        fclose($decodedfile);
  }
  echo '<h1>'.$output.'</h1>';
  echo '<hr />';
  print_r($decodedfilecontents);
}
```

And I keep getting this error:

Warning:  fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\rh-bin\func.php on line 8

My questions are, what am I doing wrong in my attempt to pass on the uploaded file as an attachment? And, why does $FileName seem to be empty? Also, not everyone will be uploading files, so how could I allow the submit?

Comment: Are you passing only filename or file path with filename in $Filename??

Comment: i was trying to do the same thing pass and file path

Comment: Have directory permission??

Comment: yes im so sure about that

Comment: you haven't provided relevant code, all we know is that `$Filename` is empty...

Comment: Full code plus the files that i wanted to open....

http://www.mediafire.com/download/7grty5qgtzhap5o/rh-bin.rar

i was trying to extract bin and convert it into xls

Comment: try using this code on extract.php line 18 extract_bin($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'],$destination ) ;

Comment: after trying the code 

extract_bin($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'],$destination ) ; 

show

Notice:  Undefined index: uploaded

Comment: I mean extract_bin($_FILES['bin']['tmp_name'],$destination ) ;

Comment: still same error occur
Warning:  fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\rh-bin\func.php on line 69

Comment: what print_r($_FILES['bin']); gives on extract.php?

Comment: using print_r($_FILES['bin']); gives on extract.php error gives

show notice: undefined index

Comment: okay guys i fixed it thank you for all of your idea,answers o.o i just update my php extentions

Answer (score 0):

`print_r($Filename)` to check if it prints anything

Answer (score 0):

check $Filename is empty or not before passing to fopen(). // it is good practice.

According to your question, your saying that not every one is uploading file, then your calling this function every time with empty value while not uploading the file also check this and make sure.